# AFURLConnectionOperation + NSURLConnection behaves differently under iOS5.1 & iOS6.0?

Tags: ios6, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, afnetworking, nsurlcache

I am seeing an issue with iOS6, AFNetworking and NSURLConnection that doesn't make any sense.

To reproduce the issue

- Make a request, any request, and make sure its successful
- Turn off the internet connectivity
- Launch the app again and make the same request again

**iOS5.1**

> ```
> 2012-10-09 15:30:43.667 CACHE TEST[3811:1bb03] <NSMutableURLRequest http://myserver.in/someImage.png>
> 2012-10-09 15:30:43.674 CACHE TEST[3811:1bb03] -[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:didReceiveData:]
> 2012-10-09 15:30:43.675 CACHE TEST[3811:1bb03] -[AFURLConnectionOperation connectionDidFinishLoading:]
> ```

Data is picked up [from NSURLCache I assume], and `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called.

**iOS6.0**

> ```
> 2012-10-09 15:32:34.578 CACHE TEST [3877:1e903] <NSMutableURLRequest http://myserver.in/someImage.png>
> 2012-10-09 15:32:34.578 CACHE TEST [3877:1e903] -[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:didFailWithError:]
> ```

Data is NOT picked up [I verified that the NSURLCache's Cache.db does have that image in the sqlite db as a blob], and `connection:didFailWithError:` is called.

I did not find anything in the API diffs that would suggest that there's been any *relevant* change in either NSURLConnection, NSURLRequest or NSURLCache.

The result is that while the success block is called when the app is run offline on 5.1, the failure block gets called on iOS6.0

**UPDATE**

Wrote a test to confirm that the NSURLConnection, NSURLRequest or NSURLCache do not behave differently.

Find it at http://github.com/abhinittiwari/NSURLCacheTest

Comment: Having the same problem. You can also reproduce it by setting the cache policy to NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad after you've run the app and loaded the url a first time. Then make this change and run the app again. You will now get the failure handler even though it should just come from cache. The really weird thing? Make the same request a second time, and you get the success handler instead.

Comment: @mixedCase yeah. look here as well https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/566

Comment: I ended up using SDURLCache. With this library, everything works as I would expect. Too bad I need this software so iOS behaves in a consistent and logical way, but at least it's a very good workaround.